# hexdump of character vector in R?

Tags: r, hexdump

To debug Korean characters (which happen to be shown as question mark("?") in R studio), I want to hexdump character vector.  At least I want to access a char.

Answer (score 0):

https://rpubs.com/mauriciocramos/encoding

```
paste(charToRaw(x),collapse=":")
```